# Rational equation with radical

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $x$: 
$$1+\frac{1+n}{2m}x=\sqrt\frac{m}{m-x}$$.

Solving:
$$1+\frac{1+n}{m}x+(\frac{1+n}{m})^2x^2=\frac{m}{m-x} $$
$$m+(1+n)x+(\frac{(1+n)^2}{m})x^2-x-\frac{1+n}{m}x^2-(\frac{1+n}{m})^2x^3=m$$
$$(1+n-1)x+(\frac{(1+n)^2}{m}-\frac{1+n}{m})x^2-(\frac{1+n}{m})^2x^3=0$$
$$x(n+\frac{1+2n+n^2-1-n}{m}x-\frac{1+2n+n^2}{m^2}x^2)=0$$

$$x=0, \text{  or  ,   }  n+\frac{n+n^2}{m}x-(\frac{1+n}{m}x)^2=0$$

How can I solve for $x=0? ? what are the factors of the second expression

Comment: for $x=0$ we get $$1=\sqrt{\frac{m}{m}}=1$$ if $$m\neq 0$$

Comment: There is a mistake in the beginning. You wrote
$$1+\frac{1+n}{m}x+\left(\frac{1+n}{m}\right)^2x^2=\frac{m}{m-x}$$
while it should be
$$1+\frac{1+n}{m}x+\left(\frac{1+n}{2m}\right)^2x^2=\frac{m}{m-x}$$

Comment: Watch out on line 1!  Squaring both sides will add extraneous solutions.  You must make a note now that only solutions where $\frac m{m-x}$ are positive are acceptable.  That is either $m > 0$ and $x < m$ or $m < 0$ and $x > m$.

Comment: "How can I solve for $x=0$?"  Um... you just did.  If $x=0$ then $x = 0$.  That *is* a solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left[\frac{(n+1) x}{2 m}+1\right]^2=\frac{m}{m-x}$$

$$\frac{(n+1)^2x^2}{4m^2}+\frac{(n+1)x}{m}+1=\frac{m}{m-x}$$

$$x\left[\left(n^2+2 n+1\right) x^2+ \left(-m n^2+2 m n+3 m\right)x-4 m^2 n \right]=0$$

which gives $x_1=0$ and

$\left(n^2+2 n+1\right) x^2+ \left(-m n^2+2 m n+3 m\right)x-4 m^2 n =0$

$\Delta=\left(-m n^2+2 m n+3 m\right)^2-4(n^2+2 n+1) (-4 m^2 n )=\\=9 m^2 + 28 m^2 n + 30 m^2 n^2 + 12 m^2 n^3 + m^2 n^4=m^2(9+28n+30n^2+12n^3+n^4)=\\ =m^2(n+9)(n^3+3 n^2+3 n+1)=(m^2(n+9)(n+1)^3$

$\Delta=m^2(n+1)^3 (n+9)$

$x=\dfrac{m n^2-2 m n-3 m \pm \sqrt{m^2(n+1)^3 (n+9)}}{2(n+1)^2}=
\\=\dfrac{m( n^2-2  n-3  \pm (n+1)\sqrt{(n+1) (n+9)}}{2(n+1)^2}=\\
=\dfrac{m( (n+1)(n-3) \pm (n+1)\sqrt{(n+1) (n+9)}}{2(n+1)^2}=\\
=\dfrac{m( n-3 \pm \sqrt{(n+1) (n+9)}}{2(n+1)}$

$x=\dfrac{m}{2\sqrt{n+1}}\left(n-3 \pm \sqrt{n+9}\right)$

Comment: Maybe only one of those is acceptable.  When you squared both sides you added extraneous solutions.  If m is positive we must have x < m.

Answer (score 0):

"How can I solve for $x=0$ ? what are the factors of the second expression"

1)  If $x = 0$ then $x=0$.  That is the solution for $x$.

$1+\frac{1+n}{2m}x=\sqrt\frac{m}{m-x}$ if $x=0$ then we would have:

$1+\frac{1+n}{2m}*0 = 1$ and $\sqrt\frac{m}{m-x} = \sqrt\frac{m}{m} = 1$.

And yes, $1=1$ so $x=0$ is a solution to this.

2)Don't factor: use the quadratic equation:

$ n+\frac{n+n^2}{m}x-(\frac{1+n}{m}x)^2=0$

$x = \frac {-\frac{n+n^2}{m} \pm \sqrt{(\frac{n+n^2}{m})^2 - 4(\frac{1+n}{m})^2*n}}{2(\frac{1+n}{m})^2}$.

That's assuming you have made no error.

Note in line 1) where you squared both sides:  That will add in incorrect extraneous solutions.  You *must* make an note that only solutions where $\frac m{m-x} \ge 0$ are acceptable.